# Selenium with Firefox-ESR in Alpine Docker image

Tags: selenium, docker, firefox, selenium-webdriver, alpine-linux

I'm using Selenium for testing from Java code, it's started automatically with maven, when I run `mvn verify` it uses `gecko-driver` to start new `firefox` instance for selenium:

```java
final FirefoxOptions opts = new FirefoxOptions();
if (HEADLESS_MODE) {
  opts.addArguments(ARG_HEADLESS);
}
return new FirefoxDriver(opts);
```

It's working fine on my machine (and on machines of other developers) in both modes "headless" and normal. Now I'm trying to run Selenium tests with CI builds in Alpine Linux Docker container. When I tried to run it as-is, I've got an error:

> mozrunner::runner INFO Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox"
>   "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote"
>   "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.pW1sbkcv98QN"
>   Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays.

Then I installed all suggested tools (`dbus` and `xvfb`) from [this post](https://blog.bj13.us/2016/06/11/install-a-headless-selenium-server-in-an-alpine-linux-container.html) and started it before running tests:

```sh
apk add xvfb dbus
dbus-uuidgen > /etc/machine-id
export DISPLAY=:99
Xvfb $DISPLAY -ac &
mvn verify
```

but now Selenium tests are hadning for about 10 seconds and failing with error

> 1565433736375   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.1ZMsJ0Hy95V0"
>   1565433738424   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 2828
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x3E0003,name=PCompositable::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv
>
> [Child 2191] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /home/buildozer/aports/community/firefox-esr/src/firefox-52.8.1esr/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2152
>   [Child 2191] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /home/buildozer/aports/community/firefox-esr/src/firefox-52.8.1esr/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2152
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x3E0003,name=PCompositable::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

It seems I'm doing something wrong here, what is the correct way to run headless Selenium tests in Alpine Linux Docker container? I'd prefer to configure existing Docker image instead of using Selenium images, because the migration will be expensive.

---

**Update:**

Selenium version is `3.141.59`
Gecko-driver version is `v0.24.0-linux64`
Firefox-ESR version is: [`52.8.1-r0`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.7/community/x86_64/firefox-esr)

---

**Update2:**

`xvfb`, `dbus` and exported `DISPLAY` are not actually needed to run Firefox in headless mode - just run `firefox --headless` and it's all.

Comment: Version of Selenium and Geckodriver ? Also enable driver logs FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
 options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE); Post here

Comment: Just to add firefox 52-esr does not support --headless flag reference https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1423640

Comment: @RahulL thanks, firefox-v52 was an issue (updated the question with versions). It was latest Firefox-ESR version for Alpine-3.7. After updating to Alpine-3.9, I was able to install Firefox-ESR v60.9. Feel free to post your answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1423640) --headless flag is not supported in Firefox 52-esr.Headless flag was introduced in version 55 (for Linux) and 56 (Mac/Windows) . Please try on latest Firefox ESR release.